# Python Folium - Looking to add multiple Markers, each with their own JPEG / PNG

Tags: python, pandas, folium

I'm looking to build a simple Folium interactive map using Python. Within the map there will be multiple Markers, and each marker will have a JPEG / PNG in the popup.

I have successfully added a single Marker with JPEG, using this code:

```
csv_file = 'Location List.csv'
lat = 51.001591
long = -3.034212
png = '2.jpg'
tooltip = "Click me!"
resolution, width, height = 200, 10, 5
base_location = 'V:/CalibrationLocations/'
location_location = f'{base_location}/Location List'
image_location = f'{base_location}/Images'
extension = 'jpg'

html = '''
<h1 style="color:#61666b;size:48">MBES Data Example Image</h1>
<br>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{}">
<br>'''.format

os.chdir(location_location)
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
os.chdir(image_location)


def create_map():

    encoded = base64.b64encode(open(png, 'rb').read()).decode('UTF-8')
    iframe = IFrame(html(encoded), width=(width * resolution) + 20, height=(height * resolution) + 20)
    popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=2650)
    icon = folium.Icon(color="red", icon="ok")
    marker = folium.Marker(location=[lat, long], popup=popup, icon=icon)
    m = folium.Map(location=[lat, long], zoom_start=5)
    marker.add_to(m)
    os.chdir(base_location)
    m.save("index.html")
    return m


if __name__ == '__main__':
    map_layers = create_map()
```

I have also successfully created a Pandas DataFrame from a CSV file and added multiple markers, using this code:

```
def create_map():
    m = folium.Map(location=[lat, long], zoom_start=5)
    df.apply(lambda row: folium.Marker([row["Latitude"], row["Longitude"]], popup=row['ID']).add_to(m), axis=1)

    os.chdir(base_location)
    m.save("index.html")
    return m
```

I have tried the below code, which is a hybrid of the first two functions, but it only plots one Marker, not the 4 in the CSV file. It also no longer has a JPEG / PNG in the popup.

```
def create_map():

    encoded = base64.b64encode(open(png, 'rb').read()).decode('UTF-8')
    iframe = IFrame(html(encoded), width=(width * resolution) + 20, height=(height * resolution) + 20)
    popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=2650)
    icon = folium.Icon(color="red", icon="ok")
    m = folium.Map(location=[lat, long], zoom_start=5)
    df.apply(lambda row: folium.Marker([row["Latitude"], row["Longitude"]], popup=popup).add_to(m), axis=1)

    os.chdir(base_location)
    m.save("index.html")
    return m
```

Has anyone succesfully plotted multiple Markers, each with a JPEG / PNG in the popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I managed to solve this by creating a list of objects for the popup (based on the number of image files in a folder) and then parsed through this list to create each marker.

Code below in three (3) *.py files:

**MAC_Main.py**

```
from folium import Map, Marker, LatLngPopup, plugins
import os

from MAC_DictionaryList import latitude_list, longitude_list,max_lat, min_lat, max_long, min_long
from MAC_Variables import base_location, start_lat, start_long, popup_objects, icon_objects

def generate_map(lat, long):
    return Map([lat, long], template = 'template.html')


def add_layers(latitude, longitude, popup_object, icon_object):
    base_map.add_child(Marker([latitude, longitude], popup=popup_object, icon=icon_object))
    return base_map


def position_marker(map_layer):
    return map_layer.add_child(LatLngPopup())


def mini_map(map_name):
    minimap = plugins.MiniMap()
    map_name.add_child(minimap)


def find_home(map_name):
    plugins.LocateControl().add_to(map_name)
    plugins.Geocoder().add_to(map_name)


def fit_bounds(map_name):
    map_name.fit_bounds([[min_lat, min_long], [max_lat, max_long]])
    map_name.add_child(plugins.MeasureControl())


def save_map(html_name):
    os.chdir(base_location)
    base_map.save(html_name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    base_map = generate_map(start_lat, start_long)

    for lat, long, popup, icon in zip(latitude_list, longitude_list, popup_objects, icon_objects):
        add_layers(lat, long, popup, icon)
    position_marker(base_map)
    mini_map(base_map)
    find_home(base_map)
    fit_bounds(base_map)
    save_map('MAC_Locations_2.html')
```

**MAC_Variables.py**

```
from folium import IFrame, Popup, Icon
import base64
from glob import glob
import os

def shorten(file):
    shortname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
    return shortname


# ---------- MAP VARIABLES -----------
start_lat = 54.7
start_long = 006.1
file_extension = 'jpg'
resolution, width, height = 180, 5, 5
final_width = (width * resolution) + 20
final_height = (height * resolution) + 20
zoom_level = 6

# ---------- FILE VARIABLES -----------
base_location = 'Volumes/Python/CalibrationLocations/'
image_location = f'{base_location}01 Images'
png_list = glob(f'{image_location}/*.{file_extension}')


# ---------- HTML -----------
html = '''
<h1 style="color:#61666b;size:48">{}</h1>
<br>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{}">
<br>'''.format


# ---------- OBJECTS -----------
popup_objects = [(Popup(IFrame(html(shorten(png_image), base64.b64encode(open(png_image, 'rb').read()).decode('UTF-8')), width=final_width, height=final_height), max_width=2650)) for png_image in png_list]
icon_objects = [(Icon(color="red", icon="ok")) for png_image in png_list]
```

**MAC_DictionaryList.py**

```
location_dictionary = {'Location 1': {'Latitude': 54.5, 'Longitude': 1.9},
                   'Location 2': {'Latitude': 52, 'Longitude': 2.3},
                   'Location 3': {'Latitude': 54.7, 'Longitude': 5.7},
                   'Location 4': {'Latitude': 56, 'Longitude': 4.6}
                   }

latitude_list = []
longitude_list = []

for key, value in location_dictionary.items():
    latitude_list.append(value['Latitude'])
    longitude_list.append(value['Longitude'])

max_lat = max(latitude_list)
min_lat = min(latitude_list)

max_long = max(longitude_list)
min_long = min(longitude_list

)
```